# Execute Async Task Inside another Async Task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to call another async task inside an OnPostExecute. The 2nd task does not run at all it seems. I am unable to print anything from within to the logs.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray lignes = json.getJSONArray("lignes");
            populatelist(lignes);
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

The populatelist function fills an array. Inside this function, I try to call the 2nd async task to get values based on this list.

```
 protected void populatelist(JSONArray lignes){
    try {
        for(int i=0;i<lignes.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonas = lignes.getJSONObject(i);
            String fdesignation = jsonas.getString("designation");
            String fqtecde = jsonas.getString("qtecde");
            String fcode_produit = jsonas.getString("code");
            InfoStock(fcode_produit);
            items.add(new PickingListProduitItem(fdesignation,"",fqtecde, ""));

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

InfoStock() is the function that is used to return additional from a web service.

```
 protected void InfoStock(String code_produit){
    String stockURL = "http://" + mSharedPreferences.getString(Constants.SERVER_IP,"")+"//rest/v2/produit/info/code/"+ code_produit + "?stock=true";
    try {
        if (mDownloader != null && mDownloader.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
            mDownloader.cancel(true);
            mPDialog.dismiss();
        }
        mPDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
        mDownloader = new XMLDownloader(getApplicationContext(),mPDialog);
        byte[][] downloadResults = mDownloader.execute(stockURL).get();

        // Read stock info.
        String s = new String(downloadResults[0], StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        JSONObject resp = new JSONObject(s);
        PrixStockJSONParser psj = new PrixStockJSONParser(resp);
        mRepInfoStock = psj.getRepInfoStock();
        mRepInfoPrix = psj.getRepInfoPrix();


    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

I am trying to set a value in the array <> created in the `OnPostExecute` Method. However there is no `error message` and the array is *not* populated at all. Even if I try to print a log from the `InfoStock` function, it does nothing.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: _I am trying to call another async task inside a OnPostExecute._ where is that call exactly, i cannot see in your code ?

Comment: This looks like a perfect use case for RxJava

Comment: in addition to what @Sam. has said, you should not have empty try/catch statements, log your errors for exceptions, it'll help with debugging

Comment: @Sam.  InfoStock(fcode_produit) is the function which executes the Async task using new XMLDownloader.

Comment: @Rafsanjani, the code runs and throws no exceptions

Comment: that is not an asynctask.. add e.printstacktrace(); in your catch blocks and see if you are having any information in your logcat.. And what is `mDownloader` when you are checking it in if condition?

Comment: @Sam. e.printstacktrace() does not catch any errors.   mDownloader is a custom async class. I cannot read any values from InfoStock method